# select optimal state for multiple conditions in lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a list below that has different representations of states:

```
list = [[array1,0.1,100,0.04] , [array2,0.4,220,0.02] , [array3,0.2,145,0.3],[array4,0.6,246,0.06] , [array5,0.8,170,0.08] , [array6,0.3,120,0.5],[array7,0.5,190,1.1] , [array8,0.9,286,0.4]]
```

For example [array1,0.1,100,0.04] has a status of 1 based on the numbers 0.1, 100, 0.04.
Now I have three lists based on this:

```
list1 = [0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.8,0.3,0.5,0.9]

list2 = [100,220,145,246,170,120,190,286]

list3 = [0.04,0.02,0.3,0.06,0.08,0.5,1.1,0.4]
```

Now the best case for me for each list is as follows: the zero index of each list is the best case for my program

```
list1 = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8,0.9]

list2 = [286,246,220,190,170,145,120,100]

list3 = [0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.3,0.4,0.5,1.1]
```

But the problem is that each list of each list depends on other lists, and for example, maybe index 1 from list 1, index 4 from list 2, and index 2 from list 3 are the best.
How can I write an optimal mode for these conditions so that I can choose the best indices?
Thanks in advance for your reply

Comment: You will first have to decide what optimal is. How much does each component weigh when deciding which one's best? Aa you say, if the first element has optimal thing from list 1, but suboptimal from the others and thing 2 has optimal from list 3 but suboptimal from the others, which one should be called best?

Comment: Priority is given to list 1. List 2 may overlap with list 3 in a situation and the program selects the wrong presentation.

Comment: I mean, maybe index 1 in list 2 got a bigger number by mistake under certain circumstances, and to avoid that, we put another feature in twenty-three to make a better decision.

Comment: One of the solutions is to prioritize list 1 and start from index zero of list 2, and compare with list 3 each time whether the need is met or not. That is, I have two conditions, one for list 2 and the other for list 3 And if both conditions were met, I would say that this index is correct now ...
Is this attitude correct? And how should I implement it in Python?

Comment: Do the values in the elements (for example, `[array1,0.1,100,0.04]` always belong to what you listed in `list1`, `list2` and `list3` or can they be anything? I assume the "good" behavior is that the first number is small, the second one big and the third one small again.